# Unable to change Apple ID on my iPhone

Tags: itunes, ios, apple-id

I changed the e-mail address linked to my Apple ID. Now when I try to update apps or purchase them on my iPhone 4, the old address pops up asking me for the password. I cannot seem to get it to change on my phone. I can log into iTunes and purchase apps there on my computer without difficulty.

I heard some people say that your iTunes ID is different than your Apple one, But I cannot see (or find) a separate iTunes ID... when I click on my account for iTunes, it shows me my Apple ID. Any ideas?  Anyone know why it will not change on my phone but will in the computer?

I downloaded and installed iOS 5. I have already tried syncing my iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Your iTunes ID is the same as your Apple ID. I've recently switched email addresses as well, so I can confirm that you can easily change the email address.

Assuming that you've already successfully changed your Apple ID, follow the steps that Hand-E-Food mentions:

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Select **Store** (near the bottom of the section starting with *General*)
3. Click on your (old) **Apple ID**
4. Click on **Sign Out**
5. Click on **Sign In**
6. Click on **Use Existing Apple ID**
7. Sign in with your new Apple ID email address and password

   That's all there is to it!

Comment: Ive tried this but when i then access the Apps Store the previous apple Id comes up? Any one got any ideas?

Comment: I have changed service provider and apple id got restored to the previous one. Even if I sign out and sign in again it is still asking a pass for the old user in the Apps Store.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen several instances of ID issues pertaining to changing IDs. Here are the TWO places in which you can sign in/out.

As previously mentioned, you can go to your settings, then general, then store - sign out there.

Next, I would launch the App Store - go to featured, scroll all the way down to the bottom  and sign out there as well.

Now you can go to settings, general, store  and sign in with the ID you want to use. There is one caveat. If you've used a previous ID and apps associated with that ID are on your device, you will still be prompted to enter the password for that ID if the App Store attempts any updates.

The best thing to do in this case is to re-download/purchase apps using the newer ID. This also involves removing the older apps from the device AND from your iTunes library (in iTunes just under "Music" you'll see apps - these are all stored locally on your computer and could sync back to your device, causing the older Apple ID requests).

Of course, if you're backing up to the cloud, this step is a bit moot. But good to know. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone, go to **Settings**, **Store** (near the bottom), **Apple ID**, **Sign Out**.  I'm not willing to sign out on mine to see what you need to do next, but I'm sure you can work it out from there.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you've switched Apple IDs recently, that may be causing a problem: you can only change what account your iPhone is authorized to once every three months or so.