# How can I change the Apple ID associated with an iPod Touch?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ios-appstore, apple-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to change Apple ID on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28126/unable-to-change-apple-id-on-my-iphone)

I just bought myself a used iPod Touch - 2nd generation.  The person who previously owned it cleared just about everything off.

**The Problem:**

I tried to install a new app onto it, but, it asked me for the password to my Apple ID. Seeing as I'm sure the person who sold it to me doesn't want to give me the password to their account, how can I change it to use my account instead of theirs?  I've checked into the different settings but I couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: No problem! Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28126/unable-to-change-apple-id-on-my-iphone) to be helpful for changing the Apple ID on your phone.

To summarize, go to `Settings` » `Store` » click on the old Apple ID » `Sign out` » `Sign in` and enter your own Apple ID.